# return identical DF or vector instead of NULL

Tags: r, dataframe, na

users,

I have data.frames which are NULL in my results, but I don't want them to be NULL. I want them to be the same as the beginning (unchanged). I'm working on a list of files and the aim of my code is to fill all the NA with data from my other data.frames (according to the best correlation coefficient). Here's a small example:

Imagine these are my 3 input data frames (10 rows each):

```
ST1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1:10))
ST2 <- data.frame(x2=c(1:5,NA,NA,8:10))
ST3 <- data.frame(x3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

The aim here is for example, if there're NAs in ST1, ST1 must be filled with data from the best correlated file with ST1 (between ST2 and ST3 in this example)).

As ST3 has no data here, I cannot have any correlation coefficient. So NAs from ST3 cannot be filled, and ST3 cannot also be used to fill another file. So ST3 has no use if you want. Nevertheless I want to keep ST3 unchanged during all my code.
So the problem in my code comes from data.frames with no data and so with only NAs.

For the moment my code would give this for "refill" (end of my code) (filled NA in my data.frames):

```
ST1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1:10))
ST2 <- data.frame(x2=c(1:5,6,7,8:10))
ST3 <- NULL
```

But actually, I want for results in "refill" this:

```
ST1 <- data.frame(x1=c(1:10))
ST2 <- data.frame(x2=c(1:5,6,7,8:10))
ST3 <- data.frame(x3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

So for data.frames with only NAs, I don't want them to be NULL in "refill", but I want them to be identical as in input. I need this to have the same dimensions of data.frames between inputs and outputs.
If they are as NULL (like it is for the moment but I don't understand why and I want to change this), there will be 0 rows in this data.frame instead of 10 rows like the other data.frames.

So I think there's something wrong in my code in function "process.all" or "na.fill" or maybe "lst".

Here's my code and it is a reproductible example for you to understand my error (you'll see in `head(refill)` ST2 is set as NULL).
Sorry if it is a bit long but my error depends on other functions previously used. Hope you've understand my problem and what I'm trying to do. Thanks for your help!

(For information, in function "process.all" and "na.fill": x is the data.frame I want to fill, and y is the file which will be used to fill x (so the best correlated file with x)).

Geoffrey

```
# my data for example
DF1 <- data.frame(x1=c(NA,NA,rnorm(3:20)),x2=c(31:50))
write.table(DF1,"ST001_2008.csv",sep=";")
DF2 <- data.frame(x1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,rnorm(1:10)),x2=c(1:20))
write.table(DF2,"ST002_2008.csv",sep=";")
DF3 <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(81:100),x2=NA)
write.table(DF3,"ST003_2008.csv",sep=";")
DF4 <- data.frame(x1=c(21:40),x2=rnorm(1:20))
write.table(DF4,"ST004_2008.csv",sep=";")

# Correlation table

  corhiver2008capt1 <- read.table(text="  ST001 ST002      ST003      ST004
ST001  1.0000000    NA -0.4350665  0.3393549
ST002         NA    NA         NA         NA
ST003 -0.4350665    NA  1.0000000 -0.4992513
ST004  0.3393549    NA -0.4992513  1.0000000",header=T)


    lst <- lapply(list.files(pattern="\\_2008.csv$"), read.table,sep=";", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    Stations <-c("ST001","ST002","ST003","ST004")
    names(lst) <- Stations

    # searching the highest correlation for each data.Frame
    get.max.cor <- function(station, mat){
     mat[row(mat) == col(mat)] <- -Inf
     m <- max(mat[station, ],na.rm=TRUE)
     if (is.finite(m)) {return(which( mat[station, ] == m ))}
     else {return(NA)}
    }

    # fill the data.frame with the data.frame which has the highest correlation coefficient
    na.fill <- function(x, y){
     if(all(!is.finite(y[1:10,1])))  return(y)
     i <- is.na(x[1:10,1])
     xx <- y[1:10,1]
     new <- data.frame(xx=xx)
     x[1:10,1][i] <- predict(lm(x[1:10,1]~xx, na.action=na.exclude),new)[i]
     x
    }

    process.all <- function(df.list, mat){

        f <- function(station)
             na.fill(df.list[[ station ]], df.list[[ max.cor[station] ]])

        g <- function(station){
        x <- df.list[[station]]
        if(any(!is.finite(x[1:10,1]))){
            mat[row(mat) == col(mat)] <- -Inf
            nas <- which(is.na(x[1:10,1]))
            ord <- order(mat[station, ], decreasing = TRUE)[-c(1, ncol(mat))]
            for(y in ord){
                if(all(!is.na(df.list[[y]][1:10,1][nas]))){
                    xx <- df.list[[y]][1:10,1]
                    new <- data.frame(xx=xx)
                    x[1:10,1][nas] <- predict(lm(x[1:10,1]~xx, na.action=na.exclude), new)[nas]
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        x
    }

        n <- length(df.list)
        nms <- names(df.list)
        max.cor <- sapply(seq.int(n), get.max.cor, corhiver2008capt1)
        df.list <- lapply(seq.int(n), f)
        df.list <- lapply(seq.int(n), g)
        names(df.list) <- nms
        df.list
    }

    refill <- process.all(lst, corhiver2008capt1)
    refill <- as.data.frame(refill)                                               ########## HERE IS THE PROBLEM ######
    refill
```

Comment: Can you try to make this to a *minimal* reproducible example, i.e. the shortest example that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: I also tried yesterday to reduce my code to reproduce my error, but this code is the smallest I was able to do to have the same error. I have alrdeady deleted half of it. But as I don't really know where the problem is, and that each function depends from the previous function, I wasn't able to do a smaller one, sorry again. I just think that the problem is in "process.all" or "na.fill" where x or y might be not well defined.

Comment: Here it is a bit smaller but I just deleted the part which works (for the calculation of the correlation matrix). I cannot delete the next functions because they're used in the function where the error is

Comment: Agree that it needs to be cut down substantially to identify exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
if(sum(!is.na(ST3)) == 0) { 
skip whatever you normally would do and go to the next vector
}
```

This assumes, of course, that you don't have any problems with, say, a vector of 1999 NAs and one numerical value.